# How to run a local script running Airflow in the docker?

Tags: python, airflow

I installed a docker pointing to local folders where I configured my dag in real file path: "C:\Users\Rod\airflow-docker"

So far so good. I can run my DAGs without any problems.

The problem is when I try to run a script via BashOperator task. Returns error. What am I doing wrong?

the error:
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/invetory_sap.py] Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/opt/airflow/dags/invetory_sap.py", line 34, in etl_invetory_sap NameError: name 'etl_invetory_sap' is not defined

The DAG:

```html
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                      datetime.min.time())
                                      
                                      
args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': seven_days_ago,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
        }

with DAG("invetory_sap",
     default_args=args,
     schedule_interval='30 * * * *',
     dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),    
     catchup=False) as dag:     
        
        etl_inventory_sap = BashOperator(
            task_id='etl_invetory_sap',
            bash_command='python  /opt/airflow/plugins/ler_txt_convert_todataframe_v5.py'
        )
        
        etl_invetory_sap
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error. You declared it as "etl_inventory_sap" and then wrote "etl_invetory_sap" on the next line. Put back the n and you should be fine.